# Is this comparison behavior well-defined?

Tags: javascript, specifications, readability

```
var x = 'foo';
var y = 'bar';

var isItDefined = (x !== (x = y)); // true, once
var isItAssigned = (x === 'bar'); // true
```

This idiom is handy for checking for immutability mutations with Immutable.js, ie

```
if (myMap !== (myMap = myMap.set('x', 2))) { changed.emit(); }
```

IIRC the immutable map implementation returns itself if the mutation results in no actual change.

Barring potential analysis of how ugly/'clever' this is, I'm curious if this is explicitly defined behavior in ES5+. Seems to depend on left-to-right evaluation, as the same structure expressed as

```
var thisWontWork = ((x = y) !== x);
```

does not ever evaluate to `true`.

Works in Chrome (40).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, evaluation order is well defined in Ecmascript [§ 11.9.4](http://es5.github.io/#x11.9.4). `x !== (x = y)` will get the value of `x` *before* assigning the value of `y` to `x`.